# Python socket with multithread synchronization issue

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, synchronization

I am writing a code where any number of clients will be sending a request to the server. The server will collect their info into a single dictionary and will send back a reply to these clients.

What I have done so far is that:

1. a server will be listening for connections.
2. for each new connection accept, it will create a new Thread
3. In each thread a message is received and the info is stored in a dictionary.
4. Then the server will send back a reply number of values in the dictionary.

The number of values that will be received by the clients should be the same since the dictionary has to be shared among all threads.

The error I am facing is that the dictionary is not getting accessed in a shared manner. I got to know what I am facing is called race around condition.
I tried using locks, RLocks and even Condition Variables, but its not working.

Kindly help how to go about it.

For threads I have inherited Thread class and overridden the run() to do the following:

[pseudocode]

```
def run(self):
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    dc["vals"].append(data)
    # dc is shared dictionary and values are list
    dr = self.processStrings(dc) #need to access all values after updates from all threads
    sock.sendall(dr)  #this has to be sent to different individual clients back
```

Comment: Can you please share executable code ,that fails

Comment: I may not be able to post executable code because it will be checked through a plagiarism detector. So it may result in disqualification of assignment.

Comment: Race conditions aside, why do you expect the same value back for all clients? I would expect each new client will increase the dictionary by one element, which will lead to ever higher numbers being returned. Otherwise, how do you know if all clients have connected and you are ready to respond?

Comment: GIL makes sure list append is thread safe\

Comment: You can share sample code that exhibits the issue you are referring to

Comment: I will share the complete code in a different thread with exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
import time
import threading

data = {
   'key': []
}


class Thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, index):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.index = index

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        data['key'].append(self.index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        t = Thread(i)
        t.start()
        t.join()
```

Did you call thread.join when start the thread ?

Comment: what does `t.join()` do

Comment: @SakshamKumar thread.join() means MainThread should wait ChildThread complete execution before exits.